# How to handle “inside link” click on Dialog (Modal) with material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I close the modal if the user has clicked on a link inside the modal? For example they open up a modal to a login form - but there is also a forgot password link. If they click on the link the user is taken to the page - but the modal stays open?

The links would be part of the modalcontents prop - but then the closehandles are inside the modalbox?

```
<ModalBox 
  button={{"label": "Log In", "color":"primary"}}
  modalContents={
    <div className="login-form">
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          <GenericForm 
            initialValues={initialLoginFormValues} 
            fields={fieldsLoginForm}
            buttons={buttonsLoginForm}
            submitHandler={this.loginFormHandler}
          />

          {errorMsg.length > 0 && 
            (
              <div className="error-text">
                {errorMsg}
              </div>
            )
          }

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          <div className="forgot-password-pane">
            <NavLink
              to="/forgotpassword"
              activeClassName="selected">Forgot password?
            </NavLink>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          Don't have an account? Don't worry, you can <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="selected">join here</NavLink>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  }
/>
```

modal box

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

//import './ModalBox.scss';

class ModalBox extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = { open: false };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
      if(this.props.open !== prevProps.open) {
        if(this.props.open){
          this.handleOpen();
        }
      }
    }    

    handleOpen = () => {
      this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    };

    handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({open: false});

      //if there is a handle close callback - invoke it
      if(this.props.handleClose) {
        this.props.handleClose();
      }
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <>
            {this.props.button &&
              (
                <Button 
                  variant="contained" 
                  color={this.props.button.color} 
                  onClick={this.handleOpen}
                >
                  {this.props.button.label}
                </Button>
              )
            }
            <Modal
              aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
              aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
              className={'modalbox'}
              open={this.state.open}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
              closeAfterTransition
              BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
              BackdropProps={{
                timeout: 500,
              }}
            >
              <Fade in={this.state.open}>
                <div className={'modalboxform ' + this.props.classes}>
                  <IconButton className="close-button" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                    <CloseIcon/>
                  </IconButton>
                  {this.props.modalContents}
                </div>
              </Fade>
            </Modal>
          </>
        );
    }
}

export default ModalBox;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is an optimal way in production but now you can handle this with adding an `onClick` event listener to your `NavLink` element,
Your code :

```
  <NavLink
     to="/forgotpassword"
     activeClassName="selected">Forgot password?
  </NavLink>
```

Change this to the following:

```
  <NavLink
     to="/forgotpassword"
     activeClassName="selected"
     onClick={this.handleClose}
   >
       Forgot password?
  </NavLink>
```

Like move the code where you have defined how the modal box component should look like with all the imports and functions

Or just follow this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

//import './ModalBox.scss';

class ModalBox extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = { open: false };
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
      if(this.props.open !== prevProps.open) {
        if(this.props.open){
          this.handleOpen();
        }
      }
    }    

    handleOpen = () => {
      this.setState({open: !this.state.open});
    };

    handleClose = () => {
      this.setState({open: false});

      //if there is a handle close callback - invoke it
      if(this.props.handleClose) {
        this.props.handleClose();
      }
    };

    render() {
        return (
          <>
            {this.props.button &&
              (
                <Button 
                  variant="contained" 
                  color={this.props.button.color} 
                  onClick={this.handleOpen}
                >
                  {this.props.button.label}
                </Button>
              )
            }
            <Modal
              aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
              aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
              className={'modalbox'}
              open={this.state.open}
              onClose={this.handleClose}
              closeAfterTransition
              BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
              BackdropProps={{
                timeout: 500,
              }}
            >
              <Fade in={this.state.open}>
                <div className={'modalboxform ' + this.props.classes}>
                  <IconButton className="close-button" onClick= 
                      {this.handleClose}>
                    <CloseIcon/>
                  </IconButton>
                  {this.props.modalContents}
                </div>
              </Fade>
            </Modal>
          </>
        );
    }
}

  class extend home Component{
   render(){
     return(
      <ModalBox 
    button={{"label": "Log In", "color":"primary"}}
     modalContents={
       <div className="login-form">
       <Grid container spacing={1}>
         <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          <GenericForm 
            initialValues={initialLoginFormValues} 
            fields={fieldsLoginForm}
            buttons={buttonsLoginForm}
            submitHandler={this.loginFormHandler}
          />

          {errorMsg.length > 0 && 
            (
              <div className="error-text">
                {errorMsg}
              </div>
            )
          }

        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          <div className="forgot-password-pane">
            <NavLink
              to="/forgotpassword"
              activeClassName="selected"
              onClick={this.handleClose}
              >Forgot password?
            </NavLink>
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          Don't have an account? Don't worry, you can <NavLink to="/" 
       activeClassName="selected">join here</NavLink>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  
     />
  )
   }
 }
```

The whole code in one single file, this is the only solution i see without using something like redux or context api

Comment: but that will be out of scope where its defined

Comment: You can it either pass it down as a prop or use something like contxt api(i reccommend do not), but you can put both the modal code and ModalBox code in one single page

Comment: like in which file does the <ModalBox  .../> live and the the other which has all the contents

Comment: the other could be anywhere - home page etc.. or guest section -- the modalbox is just a shell

Comment: Ok then migrate the code of modal box where you have defined it to home page etc.. wherever the <ModalBox />

Comment: I solved it with a body click -- and a data attribute on the link --     bodyClick = (el) => {
      if(el.target.getAttribute("data-dismiss") === "modal"){
          this.handleClose();
      }
    }